# C# Multithreading using one connection best practise

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm use in my application **multithreading** to access one **static connection**

I see some examples about `lock` statement,but the application after a while propagate

```
cross thread exception
```

so i write a code that manage the processes in my own way ,but i wonder if it's a good practise 
or bad and will lead to future exceptions,I tested it and its work fine.

```
here is the example:
```

```
    public static DataTable ExecuteCommand(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        _dt = new DataTable();
        cmd.Connection = Cn;
        _da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        int tryTimes = 0;
        try
        {
            lock (Cn)
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    if (Cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    {
                        tryTimes++;
                        if (tryTimes == 10)
                            break;
                        Thread.Sleep(200);
                    }
                    else if (Cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        Cn.Open();
                        _da.Fill(_dt);
                        Cn.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (Cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                Cn.Close();
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Source,ex.Message, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);

        }

        return _dt;
    }
```

This code received prepared **command**, and reference the connection `Cn` to it,
 but before
open the connection and for avoiding **cross thread exception** its sure that the connection state is closed before open it .
if the connection state open ,its keep trying for 10 times and each try its wait 200 millisecond ,and if the connection state keep opened ,after the 10 times to avoid **infinite loop** its break the loop.

Comment: The connection is not thread-safe.  So even using multiple threads, you'd have to channel it down to a single one to do any database access.  Thus why do you have any interest in re-using the connection across multiple threads?

Comment: It seems like it would be a lot easier, safer, and would result in much better performance to allow threads to make their own connections.  Perhaps even to organize data access in a more business-driven way rather than having a single generic handler for a `SqlCommand` returning a `DataTable`, allowing you to focus on business operations instead of infrastructure hacks.

Comment: I do re-using connection to simple the way i code ,and i'm thinking maybe its will make better performance for using as much as i can a static members and for well management,but its seems not .

Comment: @AhmedSalameh - The .NET framework is very good about caching and reusing connection objects -- you won't be able to beat their code which has been improved over many years.